# page not found after index.php removed

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, codeigniter-3

I want to remove `index.php` from my website. I tried these steps but still not working:

- `$config[index_page] = '';`
- Added this in .htaccess from system folder:

  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase/seotutor/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
  </IfModule>`
- enabled mod_rewrite in wamp apache
- override all in httd.conf

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Step:-1 Open the folder “application/config” and open the file “config.php“. find and replace the below code in config.php file.

```
//find the below code   
$config['index_page'] = "index.php" 
//replace with the below code
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Step:-2 Go to your CodeIgniter folder and create .htaccess

```
Path:
Your_website_folder/
application/
assets/
system/
.htaccess <——— this file
index.php
```

Step:-3 Write below code in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Step:-4 In some case the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. To solve this problem just open the file “application/config/config.php“, then find and replace the below code

```
//find the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"
//replace with the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

This will help you.

Comment: HI, I tried this steps but still it is not working, <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php?/Controller/new_tutor">Sign Up</a> is going to the correct page.